# "Another Generalisation of Napoleon Theorem" . How to prove this?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

***EDIT***:

[***Introduction***]:

In geometry, [Napoleon's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20Napoleon%27s%20theorem%20states,themselves%20form%20an%20equilateral%20triangle) states that if equilateral triangles are constructed on the sides of any triangle, either all outward or all inward, the lines connecting the centres of those equilateral triangles themselves form an equilateral triangle.

---

[***Generalisation of Napoleon Theorem***] :

Let A1A2A3A4A5A6 be Convex Hexagon and

Let B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6 be apex of equilateral triangle
made on base {A1A2, A2A3,A3A4,A4A5,A5A6,A6A1}
either Inwardly and outwardly ,

then G(∆B1B2B3);
G(∆B3B4B5);G(∆B5B6B1) makes equilateral triangle.

See [image]

Note: When point
A1 concide with A2;
A3 coincide with A4;
A5 coincide with A6 Simultaneously then we get Napoleon Configuration.

---

[***OUR ATTEMPTS***]:

we try to prove it by co ordinate geometry and apply the formula to get the apex of equilaterial triangle. Then we tried to add X and Y co ordinate to get Centroid and after that the formula and manipulation become very complex.

But currently we are studying vector Geometry and complex numbers and try to learn how to prove things algebrically.

---

[***Our Question***]:

How to prove this Generalisation? Is there is any easy method or elementary geometrical method to prove this?

---

[***Some important Note***]:

(1)here Convex Hexagon means : both regular and irregular Hexagon & symbol G(∆ABC) denotes centroid of ∆ABC.

(2)in above Generalisation the description is correct but in image there is a little bit typo mistake in nameing the point {B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6} but I hope you will understand it very easily by reading the description.

[***REFERENCE***]:

(1)We first published our Result on 9 July 2021 on [Euclid messenger group](https://groups.io/g/euclid/topic/85429281#2249)

(2)then we published the results on mathsoverflow but that question was delated because we don't have any experience about how to write good question at that time but results was published by rose jolie on this [this website (9 month ago)](https://wlord.org/euclidean-geometry-generalisation-of-napoleon-configuration-answer/)

Comment: Hello friends , here Convex Hexagon means : both regular and irregular Hexagon & symbol G(∆ABC) denotes centroid of ∆ABC. Hope it helps in understanding it.

Comment: My name is jayendra Jha , i along with my friends Sankalp savaran find this. We first mentioned about on Mathsoverflow but as there was no diagram so it was removed and we thanked to Henry for editing it and we also  thanks to the person who mentioned our Generalisation here :https://wlord.org/euclidean-geometry-generalisation-of-napoleon-configuration-answer/ . Many thanks to you all.

Comment: Dear Geometers , in above Generalisation the description is correct but in image there is a little bit typo mistake in nameing  the point {B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6} but I hope you will understand it very easily by reading the description .                                                        If you have any doubts and questions then you can ask through email which I have mentioned in my profile.

Comment: I just edit the question so that any one can provide us an easy method to prove this.

Comment: This is another one of those results that falls out pretty nicely using the complex number (or vector) strategies that prove Napoleon's Theorem. Have you tried those? (Generally speaking, the Math.SE community prefers/expects a question include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps people avoid wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your current level.)

Comment: We are actually not a professional Mathematician. But we try to prove it by co ordinate geometry and apply  the formula to get the apex of equilaterial triangle. Then we tried to add X and Y co ordinate to get Centroid and after that the formula and manipulation become very complex.       But sir if just give hint , advice, techniques about how to prove this by complex numbers then we take the help from my brother to understand your technique as he  knows complex numbers and vector at High School level. Just tells about techniques so that a high school students could understand it .

Comment: Please edit the question to add any context to the body; comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden. ... As for a hint: Consider each vertex as a complex number. Looking at your image, you can write, say, $B_6=A_1+w(A_2-A_1)$, where $w:=\cos60^\circ+i\sin 60^\circ$; this says that $B_6$ is the $60^\circ$ counter-clockwise rotation of $A_2$ about $A_1$. You can express the other $B_k$ likewise. Then the centroids –say, $P$, $Q$, $R$, in counter-clockwise order— are averages of the appropriate vertices. "All you have to do" is show that $R=P+w(Q-P)$. (It may help to know that $1-w+w^2=0$.)

Comment: Thank you sir Blue ,                                     sir actually I don't know how to convert link into text as in starting when I was writing the questions there was options to convert that but now that option is not available.                But sir those link contain the same thing which I write Above ,so there is no need to paste those link there.

Comment: A link to a published article that gives purely geometric proofs to this result is available at the bottom of this URL: http://dynamicmathematicslearning.com/new-napoleon-generalization.html

Comment: @Blue ,...Sir i have edited my question as much possible...., very very sorry for being late ....., At that time , i was less experienced to this website

Comment: @MichaeldeVilliers ...., SEE HERE ABOUT "HOW TO WRITE ANSWER":https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ....and you can also click on ***EDIT*** of the question so that you could easily understand about how to write answer using tools available on website